# Changing play default package

Tags: model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using `play 1.2.4` version and I am trying to change controllers package name to `controllers.com.app`.

I am getting `error` saying

```
"Error raised is Controller controllers.app not found"
```

Is there any problem if I change the package name???

Answer (score 1):

If your controllers package name is:

```
controllers.com.app
```

Then you will need to change your routes file and append com.app to all your route Controller class references.

ie:

```
GET    /something    Something
```

To

```
GET    /something    com.app.Something
```